# Keep non-numerical columns with resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame structure that looks like this:

```
df = 
                 ds   col1     col2        col3          col4

2021-04-11 17:41:55   foo1      bar1       7263          1234
2021-04-11 17:46:55   foo1      bar1       8464          5726
2021-04-11 17:51:55   foo1      bar1       3321          2345
2021-04-11 17:41:55   foo2      bar2       7263          1234
2021-04-11 17:46:55   foo2      bar2       8464          5726
2021-04-11 17:51:55   foo2      bar2       3321          2345
```

What I would like to do is to resample this into 60m bins and getting the mean - while keeping `col1` and `col2`. However, if I just do this:

```
df_new = df.resample('60min', on='ds').mean()
```

The output will be without the first two columns. The wanted output should look something like:

```
df = 
                 ds   col1     col2        col3          col4

2021-04-11 17:00:00   foo1      bar1       6349          3101
2021-04-11 17:00:00   foo2      bar2       7263          3101
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this columns for grouping (if possible):

```
df_new = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='60min', key='ds'), 'col1','col2']).mean()
print (df_new)
                                      col3         col4
ds                  col1 col2                          
2021-04-11 17:00:00 foo1 bar1  6349.333333  3101.666667
                    foo2 bar2  6349.333333  3101.666667
```

Another approach is defined aggregate function for non nunmeric values, e.g. first value in [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.iat[0]
df_new = df.set_index('ds').resample('60min').agg(f)
print (df_new)
                     col1  col2         col3         col4
ds                                                       
2021-04-11 17:00:00  foo1  bar1  6349.333333  3101.666667
```